# Is there a high quality webcam-cover solution for a MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, webcam, smart-cover

Questions as to the nature of my paranoia aside, **right now I have a piece of sticky note covering my webcam** on my MacBook Air, which, as you can imagine, doesn't really complement the look and feel. **Is there a decent product that people have actually used** that they'd recommend to replace such a sticky note or piece of electrical tape over the webcam?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware shopping questions like this attract spam. If anyone has a problem with web searching for this product, feel free to open a thread on [meta] and we'll see about editing this or reopening it.

Answer (score 5):

What about c-slide? (http://www.c-slide.com)
1 mm thin and works with all latops and pad devices.

The cool thing is that you can open and close it without having to remove any parts from you laptop. And it's sleek, the only downside is that it is black and might not look very nice on a white MacBook frame.

Comment: I have this and it's so large that it partially covers the ambient light sensor on my Macs (iMac 27", Retina MacBook Pro 13"), which prevents them from automatically adjusting brightness properly. Currently searching for a lower-profile solution...

Comment: I had a bunch of samples from them sent over because our company was looking to buy some branded ones as swag. They're too thick. Much too thick and they cause the MacBook not to be able to full close properly.